# Why this fingering suggestion for E locrian scale?

Tags: piano, scales, fingering

[image]

I'm reading this book called "The Source" and it suggests the following fingering.

My question pertains to the right hand fingering suggestion,

the most common fingering that I've seen in scales would be 123 1234 123 12345, which happens to work perfectly with the right hand for this particular scale, with index on the Bb,

I'm wondering as to why the author would suggest 212 3412 312 34123 when 123 1234 123 12345 works?

Answer (score 3):

Because, hopefully, you are already fluent at playing a F major scale.  No need to train your fingers into another pattern when the same notes are required.

Not sure why the book doesn't follow the same principle in the LH.

Comment: "Not sure why the book doesn't follow the same principle in the LH": because the LH F-major scale starts with 5, which doesn't give you a credible option for the E below the F.

Comment: But you would finger it as for the second octave of F major:   2 1 4 3 2 1 3     2 1 4 3 2 1 3 2.  I agree with Laurence. If you've learnt all the normal scales, you already know the patterns.

Comment: For some players, each mode is a separate entity, with changed notes from parallel major/minor. They don't seem to have much or any  affinity to their parent scales. Never seen it that way.

Comment: @Tim You might see it that way now!  Why train your fingers into fluency in seven scale fingering patterns when one is sufficient?

Comment: That was my point! I never have seen modes as seven separate scales - always as offshoots from the parent. But some people do see them all as separate individuals. I stopped training my fingers in scales when I stopped doing piano exams, about 50 odd yrs ago! And I don't play using the Locrian mode anyhow!